# Write LaTeX Math Equations in Code Comments?

Tags: math, latex, comments

Lately I worked on a project in `Computer Vision` that involved implementing lot of `linear algebra` equations in the code. So I had around 2 sheets of math equations which I implemented.

I have scanned the sheets and I put them along side my project code, and as I am `LaTeX'ing` them now in a separate `PDF`, am wondering wouldn't it be nice to have these equations in the code comments just above the function that implements it? (something like the IDE being able to generate beautiful equations in the code comments from the LaTeX code I write, does it sound like a good idea?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doxygen supports to generate latex files with comments in math mode:

[related Doxygen docs](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/formulas.html)

However, it wouldn't show up in your IDE.

Comment: Thanks. It supports a variety range of languages.

Answer (score -3):

It's called literate programming. Google it.

Comment: +1: this is a useful answer, and any hostility is in the eye of the beholder, reads just fine to me.